# Is it a coincidence that I received phishing emails for PayPal after I made a large deposit?

Tags: phishing, infection-vector

I recently made a very large deposit into a PayPal account. Not long after (a day or two), I have received phishing emails to steal my PayPal information. The deposit came from eToro (I pulled out some investments) and I received an email confirming the amount. I suspect that something saw the email and is now trying to get my funds. Is this a coincidence or a sign that I have an infected device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that they specifically targeting your account. PayPal phishing is actually common place. If you did not receive any before you might have just been lucky that your email was not publicly known yet or did not make it to the ones which send these phishing mails.

It might also be that your spam filter hid previous PayPal phishing mails from you. Many of today's spam filters actually automatically adapt to the kind of mails you consider spam or non-spam and having many non-spam mails with "PayPal" in it might have caused the spam filter to consider the phishing mails with a similar content now as relevant to you too.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and it lines up with the behavior I've seen. I have received a lot of PayPal emails lately so that could be it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's likely a coincidence considering if someone knew about your deposits they'd likely already have access to those accounts. I guess it's a possibility whatever account you deposited with is compromised but then again if that's the case why would the PayPal account matter.